# Stack Frame - Exemplo

Tags: c, stack, stack-trace

Estou a desenvolver um programa para simular uma Stack, no entanto estou com algumas dificuldades em entender o funcionamento, podem-me corrigir este exemplo?

```
main(int y) {
  int j;  
  f(j+1);
}

f(int x) {
  int i;
  return i+1;
}
```

Eu fiz este esquema, para quando o `main` chama a função `f`, está correcto?

[image]

Comment: Oi, Carlos, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Ajustei a formatação da sua pergunta, mas não tinha certeza se as chaves de abertura e fechamento das funções são assim mesmo ou se foi problema ao usar `<blockquote>` ao invés de `<pre><code>`, confira o guia do markdown usado aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: obrigado Brasofilo ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No fim de contas é o compilador quem decide e apenas olhando para o código fonte você não pode concluir coisa alguma. Se pretende escrever uma ferramenta que deduza isso automaticamente, precisa analisar um programa compilado. O GCC, por exemplo, faz com que todos os stackframes sejam alinhados em múltiplos de 16 por padrão adicionando paddings. Uma forma mais segura é compilar o código para assembly (usando `-S`) e analisar a partir dai.

Primeiro, modifiquei seu código assim:

```
main(int y) {
  int j=0;  
  f(j+1);
}

f(int x) {
  int i=0;
  asm("#BREAK POINT"); // Insere um comentário no código assembly. Isso faz nada.
  return i+1;
}
```

Apenas para saber em qual ponto exato que queremos analizar a stack. Também coloquei um valor nas variáveis, caso contrário o programa teria comportamento indefinido e qualquer coisa seria inválida. Compilando então:

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $0, 28(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    f
    leave
    ret
f:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    #BREAK POINT
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Vamos analisar passo a passo. A stack cresce de baixo para cima, então consideremos que a stack começa em `esp=320`. No momento está vazia:

```
+-----------------------+  <- esp=320
```

O primeiro passo do assembly é salvar o local de onde começa frame anterior ao main na stack: `pushl %ebp`.

```
+-----------------------+  <- 312 (esp)
| 4 bytes: ebp          |
+-----------------------+  <- 320
```

Depois salva o fim da stack atual no `esp` e subtrai 32 bytes de `rsp`. O `and` que acontece com `-16` tem o propósito de alinhar a stack em um múltiplo de 16. Então fica assim:

```
+-----------------------+  <- 272 (esp)
| 32 bytes: nada        |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
+-----------------------+  <- 304
| 8 bytes: alinhamento  |
|                       |
+-----------------------+  <- 312 (ebp)
| 4 bytes: antigo ebp   |
+-----------------------+  <- 320
```

A próxima instrução é `movl $0, 28(%esp)`. Ela coloca `0` no endereço `esp+28`:

```
+-----------------------+  <- 272 (esp)
| 28 bytes: nada        |
|                       |
|                       |
| 4 bytes: j=0          |
+-----------------------+  <- 304
| 8 bytes: alinhamento  |
|                       |
+-----------------------+  <- 312 (ebp)
| 4 bytes: antigo ebp   |
+-----------------------+  <- 320
```

Na sequencia: `movl 28(%esp), %eax` `addl $1, %eax` `movl %eax, (%esp)` leem o valor de `j` (`esp+28`), soma um e coloca em `esp+0`:

```
+-----------------------+  <- 272 (esp)
| 4 bytes: arg0=j+1     |
| 24 bytes: nada        |
|                       |
| 4 bytes: j=0          |
+-----------------------+  <- 304
| 8 bytes: alinhamento  |
|                       |
+-----------------------+  <- 312 (ebp)
| 4 bytes: antigo ebp   |
+-----------------------+  <- 320
```

Depois, tem a chamada da função `call f`. Note que `call` insere o endereço atual de código para que o `ret` possa funcionar. A função inicia inserindo o antigo ebp na stack, atualizando um novo ebp e subtraindo 16 da stack. Em seguida `0` é posto na stack em `ebp-4` (`movl $0, -4(%ebp)`):

```
+-----------------------+  <- 248 (esp)
| 12 bytes: nada        |
| 4 bytes: i=0          |
+-----------------------+  <- 264 (ebp)
| 4 bytes: 312          |
+-----------------------+  <- 268
| 4 bytes: enredeço     |
+-----------------------+  <- 272
| 4 bytes: arg0=j+1     |
| 24 bytes: nada        |
|                       |
| 4 bytes: j=0          |
+-----------------------+  <- 304
| 8 bytes: alinhamento  |
|                       |
+-----------------------+  <- 312
| 4 bytes: antigo ebp   |
+-----------------------+  <- 320
```

E chegamos ao break point. Se você continuar, vai ver a stack se desfazendo a medida que as funções retornam.

Como pode ver, tem bastante coisa acontecendo por debaixo dos panos. Esse exemplo simples consumiu 72 bytes, dos quais 44 foram inutilizados. Por outro lado, ligue otimizações e vai ver que o mesmo código consome 0 bytes.

Um equivoco seu: O valor de retorno nem sempre é colocado na stack. Só o é quando é de um objeto grande, como uma struct. Um `int` é meramente retornado direto no registrador, em `eax`.